# Amzi prolog and list member predicate

Tags: prolog, amzi-prolog

I am student and I have a problem with amzi prolog. We learned at class that there is a predicate that returns true if an item is a member in a list:

`member(1,[1,2,3])` should return true.

Yet I get false.

Am I doing something wrong?

please help.

regards,
Id

Comment: Do you expect a detail answer on this 'Am I doing something wrong?' ?

Comment: I expect someone to help me understand why is this not working.

Comment: builtin member/2 it's not working ? that's hard to believe!

Comment: No sarcasm ! Aren't my comments sufficiently explicit ?

Comment: @Idob it's very unlikely that `member/2` doesn't work. It would be like saying `(1 + 2) == 3` wasn't working in C. Perhaps you could provide more context, describing where you are actually querying `member(1, [1,2,3])`. Is it inside another predicate you've written? Are you just typing that in exactly at an Amzi prolog interpreter prompt (not forgetting the terminating period `.`!). You have really provided very little information.

Comment: This is a trap for the unwary.  The Listener starts in Amzi! Prolog with `member/2` undefined, and undefined predicates simply return False (unlike with SWI-Prolog reporting undefined predicates as errors).  See more details in my Answer.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you using Amzi Prolog? There are several implementations that should be preferred in almost any context: SWI-Prolog, YAP, GNU-Prolog, SICSTus....

Comment: I am familiar with eclipse and I find amzi's debugger the closet there is to Java debugger - so it is easier for me. Is there an easy way to debug with SWI? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amzi! Prolog has [a built-in predicate](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/pro/ref_text.htm#ismember) `is_member/2` which is (semi)deterministic (does not backtrack), and it has the standard `member/2` that must be loaded via the [list.pro](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/libs/list.htm) library.

Since the definition is a two-liner, I usually just put the definition of `member/2` in my source for a project as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Amzi! Prolog's built-in predicate `is_member/2`, per [its documentation](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/pro/ref_text.htm#ismember), is deterministic and simply tests membership. It won't return all members of the list on backtracking:

> `is_member/2` is a restricted version of the classic `member/2` predicate (in the
>   LIST.PLM library) than [sic] can be used for fast testing if Term is a member of List.
>   It uses a strong unify (`==`) for testing the element.
>   It cannot be used to backtrack through the various members of a list.
>   The definition is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> is_member(X, [Y|_]) :- X == Y, !.
> is_member(X,[_|Z]) :- is_member(X,Z).
> ```

As @hardmath noted in another answer, the classic `member/2` is part of [Amzi! Prolog's list library.](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/libs/list.htm) However, Prolog is [mostly] written in Prolog, so you can easily roll your own `member/2` having to import the list library:

```
member( X , [X|_]  ) .
member( X , [_|Xs] ) :- member(X,Xs) .
```